# Python loop thought a grid -200|200

Tags: python, datagrid

I have grid x|y with coordinates -200|200, 400 height 400 long 0|0 in the middle. I need loop through all and every time when it finds something and it saves coordinates in a list[] or somewhere where I can filter all find coordinates.

thanks for any help

```
    x = -200
    y = -200
    for yval in range(400):
        for xval in range(400):
            do something...
            x += 1
        y += 1
```

this not work for all grid

Comment: What does it mean when you say it doesn't work for all grids, what grids are you mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this. Both for loops iterate from `x_low` to `x_high` and `y_low` to `y_high` respectively

```
#Limits for iterating through the grid
x_low = -200
x_high = 201
y_low = -200
y_high = 201
#List to append your coordinates to, if condition is true
coords = []
for xval in range(x_low, x_high):
    for yval in range(y_low, y_high):
        if condition:
            coords.append((xval,yval))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `x` and `y` variables is a little redundant. You can simply change your starting point of your iteration and have `xval` and `yval` represent your current coordinates.

```
for xval in range(-200, 201):
    for yval in range(-200, 201):
        # xval and yval now represent your current x coordinate and y coordinate
```

In this usage of the `range(start, end)` function, you specify your starting and ending point, and you iterate from `[start, ..., end)`